# How to get specific node PID in Node-Red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am using **Node-Red V2.2.2.** I would like to restart an specific node of the flow after an error is triggered in it.

I have managed to restart the full flow getting node-red process id. After modifying: **settings.js** in my **.node-red** folder:

```
functionGlobalContext: {
    // os:require('os'),
    'pid': process.pid
},
```

I am able to get general process pid from a **function node**:

```
var General_pid = context.global.pid
```

And kill and restart the global process from an **Exec node** sending General_pid in **msg.payload** :

[image]

Being comando.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
taskkill //PID $1 //F
sleep 4
node-red
```

But i am unable to do this with specific nodes inside the node-red flow.
Almost all info i have searched relied on **Status node** to get node specific pid,

but in my case, this is the Status node structure (no PID in there):

[image]

I have also tried to get PID based on **status.source.id** using:

```
RED.nodes.getNode(id);
```

But RED.nodes is undefined (altough RED is defined, but it only shows functions on print)

[image]

Any idea on how to be able to get the node PID to kill it and restart it? I could do it from an **Exec node**, but if there is an easier way even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

Nodes are not separate processes that can be restarted independently of Node-RED. (While some nodes may fork a new process, e.g. a python script, Node-RED has no access to this and it is all handled inside the node in question)

You have 2 choices:

1. You can trigger a restart of the deployed flow by making a HTTP call to the `/flows` [Admin API](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/flows/) with the header set to `reload`. Assuming the node with the failure is well written then it should restart cleanly.
2. Restart all of Node-RED as you are already

Comment: That is what i thought at first taking in account node.exe has a single process PID which can be accessed, but i have seen many posts from previous node-red versions (2-3 years ago) in which PID from each node could be accesed. Perhaps processes where differently handled before?

Comment: No, nothing has changed, Node-RED has always been single node process.

Comment: It seems that getting PID does only apply to Exec Nodes (which seems logical). I also had some input from openAI which messed a bit my mind as it told me it was possible (with examples) for any kind of node but was based in a Node-Red version from long ago.